# Upgrading issues

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04 to the latest Disco Dingo. I get the following message:

EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable

**"Your EFI System Partition (ESP) is not mounted at /boot/efi. Please ensure that it is properly configured and try again."**

I have no idea what this is or how to fix it. Any help would be great. Thx

Comment: Please run `sudo parted -l` then copy the results and paste them into your question with [edit]. FYI, the latest Ubuntu is Eoan Ermine which is available as 19.10 at https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop; see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes

Comment: Here is what came up after I did sudo parted -l

Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-21M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      538MB   992GB   991GB   ext4
 3      992GB   1000GB  8391MB  linux-swap(v1)

Comment: @Ottawajoe I recommend that you **[edit]** your question to include that information, because it is very hard to read in a comment, and some information may even be unavailable because comments collapse whitespace. While editing your question, you can paste it (and any other text from the terminal you end up providing) into your question, select it in your question, and press Ctrl+K to format it properly.

Comment: While ^ that is helpful and nice, it's still readable as is. You should post in your question exactly how you're trying to upgrade and all the information. If trying via gui, maybe try from a terminal.